# Symfony Forms OneToMany/ManyToOne selector problems

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I am trying to create a Form with a Category selector for a Page entity - Pages can have many categories in multiple Registries.

The relationship from Page --> Category is a OneToMany/ManyToOne with an intermediate PagesCategoryEntity that has a discriminator property (categoryRegistryId).

I have successfully figured out how to use the 'entity' Type in the FormBuilder to create ONE multiple select box. But in the end, I will need to have multiple select-boxes (for each registry) with a discriminator value in the html somewhere.

So, I need to know how to get the additional properties of PagesCategoryEntity into the Form and then how I can access them in the getters/setters of the PageEntity.

Surely, I cannot be the only person to have values in the intermediate entity that need to be accessible in the form and persistence layer?

I appreciate you taking the time to look at this!

craig

***truncated Entity and Form classes for Brevity.***

```
class CategoryEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    // other properties, getters, setters, etc...
}

class PageEntity
{
   /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PagesCategoryEntity",
     *                mappedBy="page", cascade={"all"},
     *                orphanRemoval=true, indexBy="categoryRegistryId")
     */
    private $categories;

    // other properties, getters, setters, etc...
}

class PagesCategoryEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $categoryRegistryId;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CategoryEntity")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoryId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PageEntity", inversedBy="categories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entityId", referencedColumnName="pageid")
     */
    private $page;
}

class PageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('categories', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MyCoolBundle:CategoryEntity',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->where('c.parent = :parent')
                        ->setParameter('parent', 19)
                        ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
                },
                'property' => "name",
                'multiple' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'empty_data' => null,
            ));
    }
}
```

Comment: for one to many its not 'entity' but 'collection' that you have to use.

Comment: please see my response below. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this then:

```
         ->add('categories',
                      'entity',
                       array(
                             'class'=>'Acme\MycoolBundle\Entity\Category',
                             'property'=>'name',
                             'query_builder' => function (\Acme\MycoolBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository $repository)
                             {
                                 return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                        ->where('c.parent = :parent')
                                        ->setParameter('parent', 19)
                                        ->add('c.name', 'ASC');
                             }
                            )
                      );
```

try to create a category Repository if u don't have and adapt the scripts for ur needs it works for me!

Comment: thank you for the idea, but I do not understand what you are doing here? maybe you could share some of your Repository code? I assume you are using a traditional EntityRepository?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Collection instead of using Entity!

Collection is used in one to many/ many to one

you can try the tutorial of symfony cookbook for collection forms
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

i hope it helps ;)

Comment: I did also try this, but I could not get it to work in the basic form for a new entity (selector doesn't show when no value present), plus I did not see a method to add the discriminator property.

Comment: I should also mention that I would prefer to use a 'choice' type selector and not use javascript to add/remove